# How to add condition to GroupJoin (or use multiple keys)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've got database table that stores system logs. This table has columns `SourceContext` and `ObjectId`. `SourceContext` stores information in what context should I interpret this log. So if `SourceContext` equals "Product", that means that this particular log in about "Product". Then, `ObjectId` is exact id of that object (e.g. id of "Product").

I needed to display logs to my customer. But instead of `ObjectId` I needed to display real object name from other table in database. This is what I've managed to create:

```
var query = from l in db.Logs
            join c in db.Client on new { Key1 = l.SourceContext, Key2 = l.ObjectId } equals new { Key1 = "Client", Key2 = (int?)c.id } into c_result
            from c_r in c_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join p in db.Product on new { Key1 = l.SourceContext, Key2 = l.ObjectId } equals new { Key1 = "Product", Key2 = (int?)p.id } into p_result
            from p_r in p_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join w in db.Warehouse on new { Key1 = l.SourceContext, Key2 = l.ObjectId } equals new { Key1 = "Warehouse", Key2 = (int?)w.id } into w_result
            from w_r in w_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join i in db.Invoice on new { Key1 = l.SourceContext, Key2 = l.ObjectId } equals new { Key1 = "Invoice", Key2 = (int?)i.id } into i_result
            from i_r in i_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new LogsViewModel { Log = l, Name = c_r.name + "" + p_r.name + "" + w_r.name + "" + i_r.invoice_number, UserName = null };
```

It works fine, but now I need to conditionally disable some of those joins (optimalization reasons, not all contexts requre to load object names from some tables). So I decided to convert Linq query syntaxt to method syntax.

Here is what I want to accomplish:

```
public static IQueryable<LogsViewModel> GetLogs(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    var query = from l in db.Logs
                select new LogsViewModel { Log = l, Name = "", UserName = null };

    // lines below will be split in switch/case block in the future, to conditionally disable them
    query = GetUserNames(db, query);
    query = GetInvoiceNames(db, query);
    query = GetWarehouseNames(db, query);
    // etc...

    return query;
}
```

So I want to split my query into methods. Typical method would look like:

```
public static IQueryable<LogsViewModel> GetInvoiceNames(ApplicationDbContext db, IQueryable<LogsViewModel> query)
{
    return query.GroupJoin(db.Invoice.DefaultIfEmpty(), logsVM => logsVM.Log.ObjectId, invoice => invoice.id, (logsVM, invoice) => new LogsViewModel
    {
        Log = logsVM.Log,
        Name = logsVM.Name + "" + invoice.FirstOrDefault().invoice_number,
        UserName = logsVM.UserName
    });
}
```

The problem with `GetInvoiceNames` method is that it joins all logs with "Invoice" table, no matter SourceContext equals "Invoice" or not. I can't use `Where` clause or `SelectMany` because it would affect other logs. So in other words: I need to add a condition to GroupJoin so it will join all logs where SourceContext equals some specific value. Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: For optimization reasons I would do an USP and getting the data from E.F.

Comment: Just create different view models for the various use cases and you'll see that EF just ignores the joins that aren't part of the end result.